# Sending Exception from client to server over the network

Tags: c#-4.0, exception, client-server

I want to throw exception from server to client over the network like this.... this is server cod sending exception

InvalidOperationException ex = new InvalidOperationException("Duplicate Key Found");
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine(ex);

and in client side :

object serverResponse = streamReader.ReadLine();

i read object like this from server but whenever i display its type it say serverResponse is of Type System.String rather than InvalidOperationException please help me in this.

Console.WriteLine("Type Is:" + serverResponse.GetType());

Comment: i solved this issue thanks everyone for ignoring this question.